# Inlining single file components

Tags: angularjs, vue.js, migration

I'm considering vue.js as a migration target for an AngularJS (1.x) webapp.

This app loads a lot of "widgets" in its main page

```
<script optimize-inline src="data/widgets/solargraph/solargraph.js"></script>
<script optimize-inline src="data/widgets/sensorgraph/sensorgraph.js"></script>
<script optimize-inline src="data/widgets/astralgraph/astralgraph.js"></script>
```

Each one of these widgets is a custom directive which defines a custom tag.

For example `data/widgets/astralgraph/` contains the following files

```
data/widgets/astralgraph/astralgraph.css
data/widgets/astralgraph/astralgraph.html
data/widgets/astralgraph/astralgraph.js
```

and is instanced as `<astralgraph class="stickies-container"></astralgraph>` in the main page.

`.css` is pulled in by the `.html` file via the following line

```
<link optimize-inline
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="data/widgets/astralgraph/astralgraph.css?reload_times={@@ when @@}">
```

and the `.html` file is pulled in via `templateUrl: 'data/widgets/astralgraph/astralgraph.html'` in the `.js` file.

This normally causes the browser to pull in each `.js` file, which then pull in the `.html` files and so on.

Now comes the important part.

There are these `optimize-inline` markers.

These are not used by JavaScript, but are used by the Python server to inline the widgets into the main page. This way only one file is returned and no widget files (no `.js`, no `.html` and no `.css`) need to be loaded by the browser, since they are all in the (now big) main page.

First the content of the `.js` files is loaded by the server, inserted into the main page into a `<script>`-tag, but before writing that `<script>`-tag the `templateUrl` line is parsed, the content of the `.html` file written into a `<script type="text/ng-template">`-tag, like `<script type="text/ng-template" id="data/widgets/astralgraph/astralgraph.html">...HTML IS HERE...</script>`

This is the way the webapp works, it may have its drawbacks vs using webpack or the like, but it has its benefits which I appreciate a lot.

Now I've been checking out the feasibility of moving over to vue.js, and using single file components (`astralgraph.vue`) together with [`httpVueLoader`](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/http-vue-loader) solves the issue of being able to create widgets and load them without requiring a build system like webpack.

Now I'm still missing the ability to inline these `.vue` files into one big main page. How can I archive this without resorting to webpack, but by using the `with open('widgets/astralgraph.vue') as file: ...` in the Python server? By this I don't mean how do I implement this in Python, but rather how do I have to structure the resulting page so that it is a valid vue.js app.

Like in AngularJS I have the transformation from

```
/main.html
  <script src="widget/example1.js"/>
  <script src="widget/example2.js"/>
/widget/example1.js
/widget/example1.html
/widget/example1.css
/widget/example2.js
/widget/example2.html
/widget/example2.css
```

to

```
/main.html
  <!--  example1  -->
  <style>content of example1.css</style>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="example1.html">content of example1.html</script>
  <script>content of example1.js</script>
  <!--  example2  -->
  <style>content of example2.css</style>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="example2.html">content of example2.html</script>
  <script>content of example2.js</script>
```

In vue.js it would be from

```
/main.html
  components: {
    'example1': httpVueLoader('widget/example1.vue'), // optimize-inline
    'example2': httpVueLoader('widget/example1.vue') // optimize-inline
  },
/widget/example1.vue
/widget/example2.vue
```

to

```
// this I don't know
```

As for the `httpVueLoader('widget/...')` lines, I would regex them out and adapt it accordingly. It also wouldn't be an issue to load the `.vue` file into an XML-parser like BeautifulSoup to modify the `.vue` file contents as necessary before writing it into the main page. They could have an `// optimize-inline` comment in order to tell the server which components should get inlined and which not. In essence it would be a very rudimentary bundler which bundles the files on each page fetch.

For those who wonder what this astralgraph widget looks like:

[image]

Comment: If you absolutely do not want to resort to a build step like with webpack, then it seems to me that your question is essentially Python related => you should use more appropriate tags.

Comment: @ghybs I can't agree. If my only decent option is to use webpack and all that stuff, I might as well bite the bullet and upgrade Angular. The question is quite straightforward, how can I insert multiple components that are in `.vue` format into a single big file. This is not about the technical implementation (Python, Ruby, you name it), but about the capabilities of the framework, if it allows this, and if it does, how does it syntactically enable this.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your question, but it sounds to me that you specify the requirement not to use webpack, but rely on your Python server. If that is not what you mean, you might need to rephrase your question.

Comment: @ghybs thanks for your feedback. I just modified the question in order to avoid that others face the problem you had.

Comment: Let me try to understand your point: you would like an example of a resulting inlined valid Vue app, so that later on you could have a Python script that converts `.vue` files into such an inlined structure?

Comment: @DanielF I don't think `httpVueLoader` would work in your case because it requires the target SFC to be in a separate file **on the client**, which would defeat the SSR you're attempting. It seems you'll need to inline the dependencies yourself in your Python server script, and [globally register the components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Global-Registration). In a way, that work is effectively creating a module bundler, so you might as well use one already tried and true (such as Webpack with `vue-loader`).

Comment: @tony19 Yes, thanks. I would regex that out and adapt it accordingly. It also wouldn't be an issue to load the `.vue` file into an XML-parser like BeautifulSoup to modify the `.vue` file contents as necessary before writing it into the main page.

Comment: @ghybs Pinging you to inform you that I found a solution which may help you understand what I was after. @tony19 thanks, I finally understood what you were pointing at with the `globally register the components`, I didn't understand it back then (and then didn't bother to use Vue.js for some time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, but you'll lose the ability to use `scoped css`.

The normal, non-optimized setup will look like this:

`app.html`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script> 
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/http-vue-loader"></script> 
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="my-app">
      <my-component></my-component>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      new Vue({
        el: '#my-app',
        components: {
          'my-component': httpVueLoader('my-component.vue')
        }
      });
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

`my-component.vue`:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">src: Hello {{who}}</div>
</template>

<style>
  .hello {
    background-color: #ffe;
  }
</style>

<script>
  module.exports = {
    data: function() {
        return {
            who: 'world'
        }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The optimize-inline'd file will then need to look like this:

`app.html`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script> 
  </head>

  <body>

    <!--============== my-component begin ==============-->
    <template id="my-component-template">
      <div class="hello">src: Hello {{who}}</div>
    </template>

    <style>
      .hello {
        background-color: #ffe;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      Vue.component('my-component', {
          template: '#my-component-template',
          data: function() {
              return {
                  who: 'world'
              }
          }
      });
    </script>
    <!--============== my-component end ==============-->

    <div id="my-app">
      <my-component></my-component>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      new Vue({
        el: '#my-app',
        components: {
          //'my-component': httpVueLoader('my-component.vue')
        }
      });
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

---

So basically the server needs to modify the content of the `.vue` file in the following way:

1. rename the `<template>` to `<template id='my-component-template'>`
2. replace `module.exports = {` with `Vue.component('my-component',
   { template: '#my-component-template',` and add a closing `);` to the last line of the script.

Then insert this modified content into the `app.html` file and comment out the `'my-component': httpVueLoader('my-component.vue')` line, optionally also removing the `<script src="https://unpkg.com/http-vue-loader"></script>` line.